# How to apply the changes of a Linux users group assignments inside a local ansible playbook?

Tags: linux, ansible, ubuntu-18.04

I´m trying to install docker and create a docker image within a **local** ansible playbook containing multiple plays, adding the user to docker group in between:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: install docker
    ansible.builtin.apt:
     update_cache: yes
     pkg:
       - docker.io
       - python3-docker

   - name: Add current user to docker group
     ansible.builtin.user:
       name: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}"
       append: yes
       groups: docker

   - name: Ensure that docker service is running
     ansible.builtin.service:
       name: docker
       state: started

- hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:

   - name: Create docker container
     community.docker.docker_container:
       image: ...
       name: ...
```

When executing this playbook with `ansible-playbook` I´m getting a *permission denied* error at the "Create docker container" task. Rebooting and calling the playbook again solves the error.

I have tried manually executing some of the commands suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out) and executing the playbook again which works, but I´d like to do everything from within the playbook.

Adding a task like

```
  - name: allow user changes to take effect
    ansible.builtin.shell:
      cmd: exec sg docker newgrp `id -gn`
```

does not work.

How can I refresh the Linux user group assignments from within the playbook?
I´m on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a Ansible problem because it is idempotent here. I think, this happens because your user (which you use to run the playbook) is changed by the first tasks with sudo ( a different user) - but you're still logged in. Maybe there is some kind of cache or so that your local current logged in user doesn't see the changes. After the reboot (or re-log-in) it reads the environment. What happens when you try the last part with become_user: "{{  lookup('env', 'USER') }}" (asuming you don't want to run the task with root)

Comment: Are you sure about the "USER" value? Also, what may help is to print "current" user group list before the "Create container" task to ensure that you are in the right group.